# Invalid binary - missing 568h file

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, uilaunchimagefile

I am trying to submit my app to Apple Store but I am receiving the "invalid binary" message, informing that is missing the launch image for -568h modifier. But the file is in the package. I checked. Some details:

- The launch image are localized but not for all languages. They are present for English and some other languages.
- In the simulator and in the testing devices the launch image is displayed correctly.
- I checked the sizes and are correct
- I am using XCode 4.6.3
- I recently installed XCode 5 preview but I am using 4.6.3 command line tools.
- There is no UILaunchImageFile entry in the plist file (I am using the Default name).
- The images do not appear in the Launch Images panel (after I localized them).

What is going on? I don't have any clue.

Comment: Make sure that the file is named: `Default-568h@2x.png` include the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. If the launch image is localized it is necessary to provide the set of images for all languages the app supports. I tried that and Apple accepted my binary.

Comment: My app is localised for English and Dutch so I have two folder off the root called en.lproj and nl.lproj. I have the localised versions of Default@2x.png and Default-568h@2x.png in both directories (they are different per language). But I'm getting the error regarding missing support for iPhone 5. ERROR ITMS-90096. Am I doing something wrong here. I have no entries in the Info.plist regarding naming of images because I'm using Default*.png

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check your file names are like above displayed image.

Comment: They are. As I said it works in the simulator and in testing devices. The main difference between the version in Apple Store and the version and I trying to upload is that now the launch images are localized.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to ensure there are also default startup images in Base.lproj. I'm guessing they are used if you are running on a device that has a language not directly supported by the app in the other *.lproj folders.

Can anyone clarify this.

Works for me now anyway.